# Why is my image not animating?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cabasicanimation

I have imported the QuartzCore framework
[image]

I have imported the QuartzCore/CAAnimation.h file 
[image]

I have created a UIView Outlet
[image]

Here's my code
[image]

I have placed a breakpoint in my code and it does get called but the image does not move. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you verified that `leftScroll` is not `nil`?

Comment: I have nslogged leftScroll and I get leftscroll = <UIView: 0x8c6a4e0; frame = (10 319; 63 157); autoresize = RM+BM; animations = { animateLeftScroll=<CABasicAnimation: 0x8c78ae0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c75ad0>>

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I was calling the method in viewDidLoad. Apparently the call gets overridden when placed there. I placed the call in viewWillAppear and the animation worked. If someone can explain why the call can't be in viewDidLoad I'm sure someone could use the explanation.

Comment: The @"position" of your UIView cannot be animated until it is laid out, and that doesn't happen in viewDidLoad. The earliest possible time to place your code would be in didLayoutSubviews I believe.